# How can I stop _isMatchingDomain reference errors coming from Facebook referrer URLs?

Tags: javascript, facebook

This morning I got loads of javascript errors:

```
ReferenceError: _isMatchingDomain is not defined at parseCookie 
                at HTMLDocument.set [as cookie]
```

Variable `_isMatchingDomain` is not on our website and is coming only
from certain browsers:

> Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)
>
> AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>
> Chrome/61.0.3163.100
>
> Safari/537.36

Additional information from comments below:

The IPs triggering the error seem to be owned by Facebook. Possibly a Facebook crawler? ([Chris Morbitzer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52316934/530653))

The referrer URLs are all from Facebook ([Rob Wierzbowski](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52316934/530653))

Does anyone know the source of this error, if it affects users, and how to fix?

Comment: Could it be related to the AdBlock plugin? See https://fossies.org/linux/eric6/eric/Documentation/Source/eric6.WebBrowser.AdBlock.AdBlockRule.html#AdBlockRule.__isMatchingDomain

Comment: It is really impossible for us to answer this.

Comment: Getting the same thing all of the sudden 

Comment: We are seeing the same thing as well. Facebook IP Addresses.  Started 15 hours ago.  I'm not sure it's something to worry about if it's bot traffic (at least for us).

Comment: Same here - all from Facebook addresses.

Answer (score 11):

We're getting the same thing too. All of the request IPs come from Facebook-owned addresses so we think they are the crawlers executing some script. It's irritating to say the least.

Edit: I'm wondering if this has something to do with also using Piwik/Matomo? Here's our full stacktrace in one example:

```
:1:32551:43parseCookie
:1:32551HTMLDocument.set [as cookie]
https:///piwik.js:42:141c0
https:///piwik.js:48:240bo
https:///piwik.js:65:146Q.setCookieDomain
https:///piwik.js:23:60ac
https:///piwik.js:70:900c
https:///piwik.js:71:348aa
https:///piwik.js:72:279Object.addTracker
https:///piwik.js:75:386
```

Comment: All of the referrers attached to our bugs are campaigns from Facebook. Good connection.

Comment: Same here, they all originate from Facebook on my end with this exception

ReferenceError: 
    _isMatchingDomain is not defined at parseCookie 
    (eval at <anonymous> (:1:32673), <anonymous>:86:43)
     at HTMLDocument.set [as cookie]
     (eval at <anonymous> (:1:32673)

Comment: Same issue here, and also from a Facebook IP.  What's worse, the endpoint is a private URL that's not guessable... Facebook looks to be harvesting the URLs from some browser plugin or something.  SUPER shady, definition of a bad bot...

Answer (score 2):

I think it is not related specifically to Piwik/Matomo, more like to general cookie setting/accessing. We are also using Piwik, but `ReferenceError · _isMatchingDomain is not defined` gets thrown here:

```
:1:32396:43parseCookie  
:1:32396HTMLDocument.set [as cookie]    
https://trk.opentrack.org/v2:1:1253Function.b.dc    
https://trk.opentrack.org/v2:1:1979Function.b.pu    
https://trk.opentrack.org/v2e:1:121 
https://trk.opentrack.org/v2e:1:326
```